# Is there a way to cap the temperature so my wrist are not burning?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

Using a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
The heat of the place where the wrist are laying is annoying.

I cannot measure the temperature of this exact part but with the help of smcfancontrol I deduced that when the cpu is about 40~45°C this part is tolerable.

The parameters in the game are: Fan speed, CPU speed, Temperature.
Right now the fan speed is very low. Always inaudible.
I would like to trade the heat problem for more fan speed without compromising CPU speed.

Has somebody already adressed this issue ?

Comment: In my old laptop, under my wrists was where the battery was, and when the battery started to go bad it could get very hot there.  If you are still under warranty, maybe have the genius bar check the temperature control for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SMCFanControl for Mac](https://www.eidac.de/?p=260).

It's what I use when my Mac gets too hot, it increases fan speed to cool the CPU and other components down pretty quickly.

You can set custom fan speeds by clicking the application's view on the menu bar (it will say something like `99°F 1199rpm`) and clicking `Preferences` or `Active Setting`.

Comment: The trade-off isn't slowing the CPU.  The trade-off is noise from the fan.

Comment: I am already using SMCFanControl as a workaround but it does not seem to work linearly. Either it is full speed or it is not. I am expecting a software which gradually increase the fan speed when the temperature increase.

Comment: @user1707414 Have you tried going into SMCFanControl Preferences and selecting "CPU Coolant" in the Favorite selection? (you will need to click "Save" afterwards)

Comment: If you use [Macs Fan Control](https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control), you can force the fans past their normal top speed, you can also define a sensor to use as the fan speed. I wouldn't advise going over 8000 RPM, but you can if you want...